# Accessing previous values in a ReactiveCocoa -flattenMap:/-then: chain

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

Let's say I have a chain of ReactiveCocoa signals using `-flattenMap:` and `-then:`, like so:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self

[[[self fooSignal] flattenMap:^RACStream *(Foo *foo) {
    return [weakSelf barSignal];
}] then:^RACSignal *{
    // create a signal using foo
}];
```

In my case, `barSignal` is dependent on `fooSignal` completing (`next`-ing, strictly speaking, but `fooSignal` only does that once) without an error, and a `next` value for `barSignal` is nonsensical (`+combineLatest:` doesn't really apply). Even if it was sending a `next`, they're dependent operations, not parallel ones.

Obviously, I can use a `__block` variable to access `foo`, but this feels stylistically incorrect and hard to follow (not a strict chain downwards).

I can write a custom operator to achieve this, but that's much more code than a `__block` variable and would be difficult to make generic, I think.

Is there a clean way to access `foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would drop the second `-flattenMap:` and instead add a `-then:` to the end of your `barSignal`. The `foo` variable will be in scope there, and it will wait until `barSignal` is complete before being subscribed to.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self

[[self fooSignal] flattenMap:^RACStream *(Foo *foo) {
    return [[weakSelf barSignal] then:^RACSignal * {
        // create a signal using foo
        return [RACSignal createSignal ...
    }];
}];
```

Comment: This seems like the best answer to me... I took the chaining examples in the RAC documentation too seriously, but error handling, etc. works perfectly with signals "nested" like this.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this seems to be with `-concat:` and `+return:`.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self

[[[self fooSignal] flattenMap:^RACStream *(Foo *foo) {
    return [[weakSelf barSignal] concat:[RACSignal return:foo]];
}] flattenMap:^RACStream *(Foo *foo) {
    // create a signal using foo
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `-mapReplace:`:

```
_weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self

[[[self fooSignal] flattenMap:^RACStream *(Foo *foo) {
    return [[weakSelf barSignal] mapReplace:foo];
}] flattenMap:^RACStream *(Foo *foo) {
    // create a signal using foo
}];
```